# How to optimize django queries without hitting the database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a geojson file that contains more than 77 500 rows et 20 columns. With my actual view, it takes more than 30 minutes to upload the file. How can I optimize it without hitting frequently the database?

```
class Edge(models.Model):
    #geometry = models.LineStringField()
    target = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    network = models.ForeignKey(RoadNetWork, 
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Node(models.Model):
    network = models.ForeignKey(RoadNetWork, 
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    node_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField('Node Name', max_length=200)
                         location = models.PointField()
```

Here is theView :

```
def upload_edge(request, pk):

    template = "networks/edge.html"
    roadnetwork = RoadNetWork.objects.get(id=pk)
    node_instance = Node.objects.filter(
                        network_id=pk).select_related()
    list_edge_instance = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EdgeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            datafile = request.FILES['my_file']
            objects = json.load(datafile)
            for object in objects['features']:
                objet_type = object['geometry']['type']
                if objet_type == 'LineString':
                    properties = object['properties']
                    target = properties.get('target')
                    source = properties.get('source')

                    try:
                        target = Node.objects.get(node_id=target)
                        source = Node.objects.get(node_id=source)
                        node = Edge(
                                target=target,
                                source=source,
                                network=roadnetwork)
                        list_edge_instance.append(node)
                    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                        pass

        Edge.objects.bulk_create(list_edge_instance)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = EdgeForm()
        return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the target and source from the database for every single insert is a big waste:

```py
                    try:
                        target = Node.objects.get(node_id=target)
                        source = Node.objects.get(node_id=source)
                        node = Edge(
                                target=target,
                                source=source,
                                network=roadnetwork)
                        list_edge_instance.append(node)
                    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                        pass
```

Instead, pass in `_id`s, ignoring integrity errors instead of ObjectDoesNotExist:

```py
                    try:
                        node = Edge.objects.create(
                                target_id=target,
                                source_id=source,
                                network=roadnetwork)
                    except IntegrityError:
                        pass
```

You'll need to ensure that your Edge model has a uniqueness constraint on target & source, or else you'll wind up with duplicates.  This doesn't use bulk_create, but may save more overhead.  You could instead use bulk_create, but enable ignore_conflicts, in order to filter out duplicates via the same uniqueness constraint.

Comment: Since hours, I was facing another trouble "DataError,   integer out of range". How can I set my foreign keys source_id and target_id as BigInteger.

Comment: all my source_id raise an IntegrityError. For example : insert or update on table "Edge" violates foreign key constraint "Edge_source_id_e5bb854a_fk"
DETAIL:  Key (source_id)=(7223004840) is not present in table "Node". Even though The specified source_id is present in the Node table in node_id column. I tried add  to_field='node_id' in source and target column in Edge model. Since node_id is not a primary key (has duplicated values) Django refuse. Do you please any idea?